# Android application using Spotify API only works in debug mode

Tags: android, spotify

I'm making an app in android studio and using the Spotify API.
I'm doing everything exactly as in the tutorial but it only works in debug mode.
When I launch my application in release mode it can not connect to the spotify remote.

Answer (score 1):

If You check Your Developer Dashboard at Spotify You will see that Your application is in the *development mode*.

In order to create a working release build of an application using spotify API You would need to request a **quota extension** which is basically Spotify unlocking the API request limit of Your application, so that more users can use it.

Later steps would require You to create a digital footprint off of the keystore of Your release build and register it in the Dashboard.

This extension request means that Spotify would have to review Your application and see if it complies with their [Developer Policy](https://developer.spotify.com/policy/).

Unfortunately Spotify doesn't grant those extensions to *hobby projects*, so it will not be granted to the tutorial app that You have.

The lack of **quota extension** is basically the reason why Your app doesn't work when using the release build. Just refer to Your [application Dashboard](https://developer.spotify.com/dashboard/applications) and You can read about it in more detail.

Comment: I have granted quota extension but it still only can connect to spotify if its in debug mode

Comment: How did You do it? Did Spotify review Your app?

Comment: Yes it did, indeed it works when I launch it in release mode from my pc but when I download my app from google play it doesnt work

Comment: Ok, then I think You can rephrase Your question and ask once more including the information about granted quota extension and the app being already released in the store.